# What is the use of the third type in the ModelAdmin.list_filter documentation? [django]

Tags: python, django, django-modeladmin

The ModelAdmin documentation for Django 1.6 has something that confuses me. On https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter, the third type doesn't make sense to me.

The documentation says there are three types that can be used for list_filter and gives a brief example of each. The third example is:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('is_staff', admin.BooleanFieldListFilter),
    )
```

That example confuses me, because I can already pass a boolean field to list_filter and have the admin render the All|Yes|No choices, I'm not sure what the point of the third type is. Can anyone elaborate a bit on that third example and why a person would use ('field_name', admin.BooleanFieldListFilter)?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answered your question, or if it did not, add a comment and we'll resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The example in the Django docs could be clearer. [0]

You would never actually need to pass `BooleanFieldListFilter` itself in the tuple style for the reason that you stated: it is already used internally (automatically) when you have a `BooleanField` in your model which you include in the `list_filter` tuple.

That said, `BooleanFieldListFilter` is one example of subclassing `FieldListFilter`, and if you were to write your own custom subclass for working with a special field besides a standard boolean, you would pass your custom subclass to `list_filter` in this tuple style.

*Note that this should not be confused with the more common case of subclassing `SimpleListFilter`, which is [described as the second case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) in the docs.  An example of using this case would be if you had a method on your model that returned a boolean derived from the value of a model field, but the relevant model field could not be a boolean itself.  (I hope this isn't confusing with the previous paragraph.)*

0: I checked v1.7 and dev, but it doesn't seem that this has happened yet.